# Graalvm + spring 3 running on kubernetes. Unable to load a '.so' file via System.load()

Tags: spring, java-17, graalvm

I have access to the specified filed "libFilename.so" through class.getResource() or  class.getResourceAsStream() as I have defined the resource-config.json correctly for that. System.load() requires an absolute path which I can't seem to generate programmatically. Can't use System.loadLibrary (I have tried setting the java.library.path correctly and all that to see if it was a viable alternative that I could create some kind of workaround for). Creating a new File or even newTemporaryFile and copying the resource/stream to it does not work either. If anyone has a solution or even a hint to one, it would be  greatly appreciated.

Tried:

Creating new File and copying over contents of the resource/stream.

The FileSystem in graalvm.polyglot.

Variations on Classloaders and ClassPathResource.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `loadLibrary` should work as long as the .so file is in the same directory as the native image

Comment: @peterz we're using kubernetes to create pods from docker images so its not really possible to have the .so in the same directory as the native image unless you know how to achieve that .